# How to change the default size of Google Hangouts for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, google-hangouts

How can I change the default size of a chat window in Google Hangouts for Windows?

[image]

Comment: Google wonders why that app isn't more popular, but it looks and feels like it was coded in 1998

Comment: @Tyson I think it's a matter of consistency since Google web UIs tend to be quite crappy.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl key and mouse wheel forward or back to increase and decrease zoom size of window when in transparent mode.

Answer (score 0):

Readjust the window to the size you need. Minimize it, Alt-Tab it back. Expand it out till it's in fullscreen. then set, it back to it's smaller version. Close it and re-open. You're all set!